# JODIT displays content with html tags after editing in React js

Tags: jodit

I am working with Jodit editor on a react project. When I create a note and send to database, and displays the note, it displays fine, but when I try to edit the content and save, the rendered text/content now contains some html tags and this "<p><". I have tried using renderHTML to convert it to only plain text, but that doesn't seem to work. I really need help on converting to plain text alone. The render renderHTML works fine when creating a new note, but doesn't convert to plain text when I try to edit the content.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use the Jodit contents in a non-Jodit environment, you'll need to use a utility that converts the HTML tags.

One library that does this already is `html-to-text`.

On the backend, the actual code is as simple as

```
const { conversion } = require('html-to-text');
let adjustedText = conversion('<p>Your string of HTML code here</p>');
```

... unless you want to feed optional parameters to the conversion() function, like wordwrap. See html-to-text documentation for that.

Comment: I tried usin danngerouslysetinnerhtml, & it was converted well on creating, but the issue I have now seems to be on editing, there are some special characters that affects the display when I tried to  console log the txts I was gettng after editing. it adds this characters to it "&lt;p>&lt;strong>" . this ends up messing up the display even with the dangerouslysetinnerhtml that I used, because the strong tag is not properly created. if those characters are not included the dangerouslysetinnerhtml wil remve the html tags, which in this case would be strong.challenge is removin those characters.